# unexpected eof error in bash file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm creating a small program that does some simple math, but cannot run it. It just outputs "Unexpected end of file." I can't seem to find the error.. ?

```
#!/bin/bash

until [ $second_num -ne 0 ]; do
    echo "Enter number 1:"
    read first_num
    echo "Enter number 2:"
    read second_num
    echo "Cannot divide by 0. Start over."
done

result=0
if [ $first_num -ne 999 && $second_num -ne 999 ]; then
    let result=$((first_num/second_num))
    echo $result    
    echo "Program finished!"
else
    echo "You have exited the program."
    exit 0 
fi  

number=1
while [ $number -lt 100 ]; do
    echo $number
    let number=$(( $number % 5 ))
    echo $number >> sample.txt
done
```

Comment: Learn to use: `sh -x`, and `sh -nv` to debug this.  Usually, unexpected EOF means a problem with unmatched quotes or something similar, or an incomplete loop construct.  It isn't clear why you report `Cannot divide by 0` without testing anything.  I'm suspicious that the code you show isn't the code you're trying to debug; the code you show doesn't give the error you say.  The `&&` in the `if` should be written `-a` — that is a defect.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance I see 2 issues with your script:

- `until [ $second_num -ne 0 ]; do`

  You don't initialize `$second_num`, so you're trying to compare 0 to nothing.
- `if [ $first_num -ne 999 && $second_num -ne 999 ]; then`

  `&&` is a [conditional execution operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html). The AND operator for two expressions inside (single) square brackets is `-a`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but the following code should work fine without any error

```
 #!/bin/bash

until [ $second_num -ne 0 ]; do
    echo "Enter number 1:"
    read first_num
    echo "Enter number 2:"
    read second_num
    echo "Cannot divide by 0. Start over."
done

result=0
if [ "$first_num" -ne "999" -a "$second_num" -ne "999" ];

then
    let result=$(($first_num/$second_num))
    echo $result    
    echo "Program finished!"
else
    echo "You have exited the program."
    exit 0
fi

number=1
while [ $number -lt 100 ]; do
    echo $number
    let number=$(( $number % 5 ))
    echo $number >> sample.txt
done
```

Comment: It will run, but it will still show a warning due to the uninitialized `$second_num`.

Answer (score 0):

i executed under bash version 4 and no problem(no syntax error),
but some semantics errors, variable second_num is undefined and && in if statement 
line 3: [: -ne: unary operator expected
Enter number 1:
34
Enter number 2:
54
Cannot divide by 0. Start over.
 line 12: [: missing `]'
You have exited the program.

send you script again